# Thunderbird loses all settings if PC is being shut down abnormally

Tags: windows, thunderbird

If my PC shut downs suddenly with power dips, etc., I lose all my Thunderburd settings and mail in Thunderbird, although the Profiles folder still exists. I had a look in the profiles text file and that file looks unchanged. Are there things I could try to solve this issue?

I do not know what do do? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

OS: Win XP Professional SP2
Thunderbird Version: 2.0.0.19

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I assume that every now and then Thunderbird is shutdown normally, right? (In other words: Thunderbird did at least once have the chance to save any changed preferences upon normal exit, right? So, it loses settings that were previously saved?)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have thunderbird open when this happens, also are any other applications affected?

It would probably be a good idea to make a backup of your tb profile, which you could do simply by copying the profile folder and all sub directories to an alternate location, or you could use a utility designed for the task:

http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/download.php

At least this will ease the pain of restoring the profile and mail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force your profile to a particular location without opening the the last used profile...

Edit `%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\profiles.ini` to be something like this:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=0
Path=<insert absolute path to your profile folder>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use IMAP or POP3? If POP3, you can at least go to your profile folder, examine the .mbox files in a text editor to see if anything is missing. If nothing else helps, you can re-import the plain mbox files with this plugin: http://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html

Not nice, and presumably there is a better way to recover the profile, but it's a fallback solution.